# How to add new SP to PingFederate

Tags: pingfederate

I want to deploy 2 Web Applications and 1 IDP.
I call SP1, SP2 and IDP.

I look on agentless kit example
when SP1 need login, it wil redirect to /sp/startSSO.ping?PartnerIdpId=PF-DEMO and PF will redirect to IDP 
When I finish login IDP will redirect to /idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=PF-DEMO
PF will redirect back to SP by lookup URL from [Application Integration Settings -> Default URLs]

If request come from SP2 how to mapping URL to redirect back to SP2?
How IDP know what request come from which SP?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what stumbling block you are having or what version of PingFederate you're using, but in 7.1 that was released late-2013 there was a Default SP URL setting introduced at the IdP Connection layer (that overrides the global one you're referencing) that might help.

Details in the following section of the PF documentation:

- https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FserviceProviderSsoConfiguration.html
- https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FconfiguringDefaultTargetUrlOptional.html

(Release notes from 7.1 release: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=releaseNotes/PingFederate_7.1_-_August_2013.html)

Edit: Additionally, you might not be setting the RelayState value with the target URL (SP) you're trying to send the user to.  For example, if you're doing IdP Init SSO, PingFederate as the IdP can set this value in the TargetResource parameter.  For details, see: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FidpEndpoints.html

Comment: Hi Scott, thank for you document. For now I use PFv6.1.
I am new with PingFederate. I try to understand my situation.